# Thread stuck in IN_NATIVE state while downloading a file from webservice

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

I am downloading a file from X service thru my code. The downloaded file is written on file system. 
Issue I am facing is that my instance is stuck and not taking further jobs to process. In the thread dump I see most of the threads in IN_NATIVE state.

Can you please help me where I am going wrong?

```
    Thread 25493: (state = IN_NATIVE)
     - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
     - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=87, line=152 (Compiled frame)
     - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=122 (Compiled frame)
     - sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(java.io.InputStream, byte[], int, int) @bci=21, line=442 (Compiled frame)
     - sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(java.io.InputStream, java.io.OutputStream) @bci=32, line=480 (Interpreted frame)
     - sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(sun.security.ssl.InputRecord, boolean) @bci=44, line=927 (Interpreted frame)
     - sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(sun.security.ssl.InputRecord) @bci=15, line=884 (Interpreted frame)
     - sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=72, line=102 (Interpreted frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer() @bci=71, line=160 (Compiled frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer() @bci=1, line=84 (Compiled frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer) @bci=130, line=273 (Compiled frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer) @bci=16, line=140 (Compiled frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer) @bci=2, line=57 (Compiled frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse() @bci=38, line=260 (Compiled frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader() @bci=8, line=283 (Compiled frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader() @bci=1, line=251 (Compiled frame)
     - org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader() @bci=6, line=197 (Compiled frame)

 - org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=41, line=271 (Compiled frame)
```

Below is the code which is handling imputstream from X service

```
public void handleResponse(Response response, InputStream responseStream) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try {
        if (response != null && responseStream != null) {
            bis = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(responseStream);
            //code writing to disk 
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("IOException while writing file " + fileName + " to disk ", e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("IOException while writing file " + fileName + " to disk ", e);
    }
    finally {
        if (bos != null) {
            bos.close();
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
        if (bis != null) {
            bis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream is waiting for more data from the service.
Maybe the service isn't closing the connection properly or maybe you fail to detect that the stream has ended (read the bytes until it sends -1).

Comment: Yes, I am reading the bytes until -1. That part of code was replaced with //code writing to disk
                       byte []buffer = new byte [65536];
                       int available  = -1;
                       while((available = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {   
                           bos.write(buffer, 0, available); 
                       }  
                       
                       bos.flush();

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be while((available = bis.read(buffer)) > -1)